# How to make setting persistent with 'adb shell settings'

Tags: android, adb, settings, call-recording

The next command enables phone call recording in OnePlus phones (may be others too):

```
adb shell settings put global op_voice_recording_supported_by_mcc 1
```

But after reboot its effect is disabled. My phone is OnePlus 6T.

How to make this setting persistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOnePlus Tools is an answer. This application sets settings up on every reboot.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this APP and now I have call service activated by default. Although I have to open the APP apply the settings at each reboot

Comment: There is an option "auto apply on start up" so no need to reapply settings every reboot

Comment: I don't find that option in the APP settings. Is it enabled only for root devices?

Comment: My device is not rooted

Answer (score 1):

https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-5/themes/app-enable-call-recording-boot-t3634292

This link has other root-required methods you might want to try.

Unfortunately, I am also trying to find a way without root. As the setting automatically turns off, sometimes before reboot, when you have an active some-country sim card, my hypothesis is that there is a "checking" program going on under the hood. If there is an adb command to turn off that "checking", the result should be permanent.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a 6T, and what I could see about what causes recording to be disabled, is any application installation made by PlayStore.
If you keep the automatic update function of the applications deactivated, the recording remains activated, but anytime you do any installation on the PlayStore, the recording will be disabled and you will need to enable it with the command again.

Comment: It's actually worse. If you switch to airplane mode and then restore network connectivity the same will happen. It seems on Android 11 they added a region check whenever some change occurs on the phone, which disables call recording when they realize you're not in India (where it's enabled).